# More options for low quality posts

Tags: feature-request, moderation, flagging

As I have recently passed the 10k reputation threshold, Stack Exchange is now asking me for more moderation work, including handling low quality posts. The interface for this task seems inadequate to me.

When a low-quality post is reported, I have only four options: Looks ok, Edit, Recommend deletion, and Skip.

- What is the effect of Recommend Deletion? Does the post get deleted immediately, or does it get passed to a "lozenge" moderator? How many such recommendations are needed? Documentation and contextual help is lacking.
- What if I want to flag the post as "should be a comment", for instance? The moderation page contains a copy of the answer, but the "flag" link isn't there. I need to navigate to a different page, with at least four clicks, to recommend that a low-quality answer should be a comment. This seems bad UI for a reasonably common task.
- Are the (allegedly) low-quality posts that I see in the moderation queue determined automatically, or based on some user flagging them? If it's the latter, I think that the interface should tell me who flagged it.

Comment: My guess is this has been covered on the main meta. I will try and take a look later.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an [intensive FAQ on reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/255554) on Meta SE. Do not trust on the documentation in the review interface or what’s written on the buttons, [it’s misleading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220794/255554).

As the linked post does a good job of explaining things, I will keep my answers to your individual points brief:

- > What is the effect of Recommend Deletion? Does the post get deleted immediately, or does it get passed to a "lozenge" moderator? How many such recommendations are needed?

  If six users with less than 20 k recommend deletion, the post gets immediately deleted. Users with more than 20 k count double.
- > What if I want to flag the post as "should be a comment", for instance? The moderation page contains a copy of the answer, but the "flag" link isn't there. I need to navigate to a different page, with at least four clicks, to recommend that a low-quality answer should be a comment.

  The canned comments you can select when you “recommend deletion” are just that: comments. They do not have any further effect. If you think that an answer should be a comment, flag it for moderator attention.

  Having a flag button in the low-quality queue has already been requested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237955/255554).
- > Are the (allegedly) low-quality posts that I see in the moderation queue determined automatically, or based on some user flagging them?

  Both. In that queue you get automatically identified posts (this is also called a *flag*) as well as posts which have been flagged as *not an answer* or *very low quality.*
- > As I have recently passed the 10k reputation threshold, Stack Exchange is now asking me for more moderation work, including handling low quality posts.

  As a sidenote: The only thing that changed when you obtained 10 k reputation in this respect is that you now get an alert in the top bar if there are more than two posts to review. You could review low-quality posts since you have reached 2 k reputation.

  The main new ability that you got is casting delete votes on closed questions (older than two days). Also, you get to see deleted posts, reviews by other users as well as all the information available [on this page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tools).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. This gives me all the information I need. Nevertheless, I will not accept this answer, though, because I would like to see a better interface and documentation on the page itself, so the feature-request is still open.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni while the SE team looks at the individual metas, it is often better to ask things like this on the main meta. One exception is for things that do not scale well, but I think in this case, your suggestion applies equally to all SE sites.